# Categories Not Saving CE 2.1.5

Tags: magento2, category, database, magento2.1.5

I've been working on getting things setup in my store and so far everything is good. I created categories and spent time loading them up with products. But it seems somewhere along the way I've lost the ability to create and edit categories from the admin.

When I save an existing category nothing changes. Nothing gets written to the database. There's no errors in any of the logs, neither the apache logs or the magento logs.

When creating a new category, I can see a record gets inserted into the catalog_category_entity table, but there's no reference in any other table. So I end up creating categories with no info attached (such as name, content etc..). They actually show up in the category tree as a no named category that I can't edit.

I've tried clearing cache, reindex, setup:upgrade, recompile.. nothing makes a difference.

Has anybody else seen this? I'm not sure what's going on since there's nothing 
logged anywhere.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Magento CE 2.1.5
MySql 5.7.17
PHP 7.0.17
Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened, but I realized a lot of key data was missing from some of the attribute entity tables. I ended up rolling back to my last backup and I seem to be up and running again.